# puppet agent not able to connect to master

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

on master:

```
puppetserver ca list Traceback (most recent call last):
9: from /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/cli/apps/ca:5:in '<main>'
8: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/cli.rb:94:in 'run'
7: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/list.rb:78:in 'run'
6: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/list.rb:167:in 'get_all_certs'
5: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/list.rb:167:in 'new'
4: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/certificate_authority.rb:26:in 'initialize'
3: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/certificate_authority.rb:26:in 'new'
2: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:23:in 'initialize'
1: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:144:in 'make_store'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:144:in add_file': system lib (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
```

On agent:

> osboxes@ubuntuagent:~$ sudo ufw disable
>
> Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup osboxes@ubuntuagent:~$
> osboxes@ubuntuagent:~$ sudo systemctl restart puppet
> osboxes@ubuntuagent:~$ sudo systemctl status puppet ● puppet.service -
> Puppet agent    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/puppet.service;
> enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: active (running) since Tue
> 2020-08-04 08:56:55 EDT; 12s ago  Main PID: 6239 (puppet)
> Tasks: 2 (limit: 2321)    Memory: 45.5M    CGroup: /system.slice/puppet.service
> └─6239 /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/ruby /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent --no-daemonize
>
> Aug 04 08:56:55 ubuntuagent systemd[1]: Started Puppet agent. Aug 04
> 08:56:59 ubuntuagent puppet-agent[6239]: Request to
> https://ubuntuserver:8140/puppet-ca/v1 failed after Aug 04 08:56:59
> ubuntuagent puppet-agent[6239]: Wrapped exception: Aug 04 08:56:59
> ubuntuagent puppet-agent[6239]: Failed to open TCP connection to
> ubuntuserver:8140 (Connection Aug 04 08:56:59 ubuntuagent
> puppet-agent[6239]: No more routes to ca

Answer (score 1):

Your certficates are configured incorrectly, most likely on the server side. This is indicated by this line:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-1.8.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:144:in add_file': system lib (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
```

Comment: These certificates came with the default installation only, I didn't configure them, could you please guide how to rectify this.

Comment: @UdayKiranReddy I hope this helps: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.3/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#concept-4386

Comment: @UdayKiranReddy I've been down this road before, if you don't properly add them to a DNS server and then regenerate your certificates you get errors like this, if I recall correctly.